# get hidden form value and show in modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

below is the form on my page. In each row you see a hidden value with a name of "unitType". What i would like to do is click a button on each row, get the value of that particular row's unitType hidden value and pop up a bootstrap modal and set the modals image tag src with the value from the hidden field and concatenate the rest of the path to show the corresponding image in the bootstrap modal.

Hopefully this is the correct way to ask here.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Location</th>
                <th scope="col">Serial #</th>
                <th scope="col">Level</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr scope="row">
                <td class="align-middle">East Entrance (Elvis Car)</td>
                <td class="align-middle">CR5E180022B</td>
                <td><input type="number" name="LevelAmount[]" class="unitType form-control" value=""></td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Image</button></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" class="unitType" name="unitType" value="Sienna 5 B.png"></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="S1149"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr scope="row">
                <td class="align-middle">Hotel Elevator Bthrm - Womens</td>
                <td class="align-middle">CS3G170159</td>
                <td><input type="number" name="LevelAmount[]" class="unitType form-control" value=""></td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Image</button></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" class="unitType" name="unitType" value="Sienna 3.png"></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="S1151"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-right"><input type="hidden" name="SessionID[]" value="">
        <input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</div>
```

the html below is my bootstrap modal code.

```
<div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Diffuser</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <img id="unitType" src="">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the updated answer

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var ele = $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type="hidden"]').val()
  alert(ele)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Location</th>
          <th scope="col">Serial #</th>
          <th scope="col">Level</th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr scope="row">
          <td class="align-middle">East Entrance (Elvis Car)</td>
          <td class="align-middle">CR5E180022B</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="LevelAmount[]" class="unitType form-control" value=""></td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Image</button></td>
          <td><input type="hidden" class="unitType" name="unitType" value="Sienna 5 B.png"></td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="S1149"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr scope="row">
          <td class="align-middle">Hotel Elevator Bthrm - Womens</td>
          <td class="align-middle">CS3G170159</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="LevelAmount[]" class="unitType form-control" value=""></td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Image</button></td>
          <td><input type="hidden" class="unitType" name="unitType" value="Sienna 3.png"></td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="S1151"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-right"><input type="hidden" name="SessionID[]" value="">
      <input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: alert box just comes up with "undefined"

Comment: I updated the answer. Now, it gives the value for hidden field correctly.

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm. Now to just write the code to set the img src of the modal and ill be set. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Got the bootstrap modal to show the image now. Just need to resize the image way down lol. Again thanks a million for the help!